# Hiding input field

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com, controller

I want to hide the below bold input fields. Is there any easy way i can do it. I tried using `style="display:none;"` but it does not work. Thanks

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 9: Optional Section" collapsible="false" columns="2"  ><br/>

  <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.System_Size_SUB_2013__c}"/><br/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Heating_Type__c}" style="display:none;"  /><br/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Motor_Type__c}"/><br/>

  <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Temperature_Control_Unit__c}"/>  <br/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.TCU_Hose_Kit__c}"/><br/>

<apex:pageBlockSection><br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you said it, it looks like you tried to add the style directly to the inputField tag. I believe you can put your three input fields inside a **div**, and in this div you put the style `display:none;`.

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <field>
    <field>
    <field>
</div>
```

Source for my answer is [Ispita_Navatar's answer at the Salesforce Developers website](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097elIAA).

**Alternate Solution**

Apparently you can also add the attribute `rendered` to the field, and set it to `false`.

[Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm).

Comment: You can also disable rendering of Input Field using rendered option. Like <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}" rendered="{!flag1=='Value1'}"/>

Comment: What Dave said apparently is also true. I've updated my answer with his solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide input field there are 2 ways to achieve this:-

1. Place your input field in div and set visibility of the div to say display =none. Do refer to the snippet below for clarity
2. Or use    instead of  and assign value in inputhidden field using javascript.

Refer to this link to know about apex:inputHidden : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputHidden.htm